# Animated js/jquery function do not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to do function which is changing with animation div position and its not working :(

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function moveAnimate(x, y, element) {
    var leftX = document.getElementById.style.left;
    var topY = document.getElementById.style.top;
        leftX += x
        topY += y
           $('"#"+element').animate(
            { 
                "top": "topY", 
                "left": "leftX",
            },
            1000);

};
});
```

I called function:

```
<div id="divv" onclick="moveAnimate(300, 400, divv)"></div>
```

Comment: "It's not working" is not enough on here. Post error messages, what you want it to do, what you need help with, ...

Comment: Do you mean `leftX` instead of `"leftX"`?

Comment: Yeah, my bad but still won't work

Comment: Umm, getElementById does not say which element it is looking for...

Comment: when is `moveAnimate` called? please include the rest of your code

Comment: Agustin still not working

Comment: You forget using `;`. And be sure that the element is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Check your code JS syntax again. document.getElementById is a method so it has to be:

```
var leftX = document.getElementById(element).style.left;
var topY = document.getElementById(element).style.top;
```

And animate function should like this:

```
$('#'+element).animate({
    //your code here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `moveAnimate` is defined within `$(document).ready(function() {})` scope.
However, you try to call it from global context.

You need to define your function outside of `$(document).ready` in order to make it available in your `onclick` attribute.
Much better, use `jQuery.on('click')` to attach handler:

```
function moveAnimate(x, y, element) {
    var leftX = document.getElementById.style.left;
    var topY = document.getElementById.style.top;

    leftX += x;
    topY += y;

    $(element).animate({ 
        "top": topY, 
        "left": leftX,
    }, 1000);    
}; 

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#divv").on("click", function() {
        moveAnimate(300, 400, this);
    });
});
```

Note that I have also fixed some syntax and logical errors in your `moveAnimate` function.

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I just copy-pasted your code and won't work ...

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong, I've made some changes:

```
function moveAnimate(x, y, element) {
    var leftX = document.getElementById(element).style.left;
    var topY = document.getElementById(element).style.top;
    leftX += x;
    topY += y;
    $('#'+element).animate(
    { 
      "top": leftX, 
      "left": topY,
    },
    1000);

};
```

You should read the documentation...
http://api.jquery.com/animate/